# Message Passing between Chrome Extension and Content Script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've read through the [Message Passing Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and tried to utilize it in my code as follows:

**contentscript.js:**

```
var buttonEl = document.getElementById("activateBtn");

if (buttonEl) {
    buttonEl.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("activateBtn clicked! " + chrome.runtime.sendMessage);

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({button: buttonEl});
    });
}
```

**backgroundscript.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("onMessage:", request);
});
```

The goal is to let the content script be injected into a page (specified in the manifest.json) and then run.
The script is running just fine - the alert message get's displayed, but the message is not send. Or not received. Either way, that button holds an ID which I need to pass to my privileged background code someway.

When I run the code in the developer console of the extension I receive the message just fine - so the receiving end seems to work.

Any leads on the problem?

Thank you for you time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the injected page's console, you should see something like

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

This is because you are trying to pass an HTML object through JSON. Try passing just the ID of the button instead and see if it works then.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Do you also know where I can see such errors? When I open the console of the page where the content script gets injected I don't see any errors ..